# How to validate textbox in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to validate textbox. I am using ng-required="true", but its not showing required message. If i click save button, it directly place to save() function. How to avoid it.

```
<div ng-app="LearnApp" ng-controller="csrControl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Name
            </td>
            <td>
                :
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtName" type="text" ng-model="txtName" ng-required="true" placeholder="Name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Address
            </td>
            <td>
                :
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtAddress" type="text" ng-model="txtAddress" ng-required="true" placeholder="Address" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="right">
                <input id="btnSave" type="button" value="Save" class="button" ng-click="save()" />
                <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" class="button" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("LearnApp", []);
    app.controller("csrControl", function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.save = function () {

        };

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try it with just 'required', not ng-required="true"

Comment: Please check form validation in angularjs

Comment: Which message do you expect to see? I don't see any html that contains (error) messages. Or do you just want to trigger the html5 validation?

Comment: yes just trigger  out html5 validation

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the Form tag.

```
<form name="myForm" >
  ....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add form tag and also give name to form. And use this name for error message like:

```
 <form name="myForm" novalidate>

    //some code

    <input type="text" ng-model="abc" name="txt1" ng-required="true"/>
        <div ng-messages="myForm.txt1.$error">
            <div ng-message="required"> This is Required! </div>                                       
        </div>
 </form>
```

And also put condition on server side to validate form before save:

```
   $scope.Save = function () {
          if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {

             //perform save

           }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **form** tag and **ng-submit** which will call the provided function if your form is valid or throw the default html5 validation error. Using just the **"required"** attribute will make the input required. Use ng-required if you have to evaluate an expression that can be assigned to the ng-required directive.

If you want specific type of error message and avoid default html5 validation, you can use **novalidate** directive in the form tag. 
For more information on Angular form validation , the official [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation) would help.

Check the below changes to your code.

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>
        <td>
            :
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="txtName" type="text" ng-model="txtName" required placeholder="Name" />
        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="right">
            <input id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save" class="button"/>
            <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" class="button" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```